# Responsive display issue - menu not showing up in alternate form upon resizing

Tags: php, html, css

As the title states I am having an issue when the site I'm working on is resized from desktop down to Ipad Air / Mini resolution, the alternate drop down menu nor the full size menu show up. I'm new to responsive layout so any help is appreciated.

The site is at a testing link here @   rdesignmedia.com/itechrepairs

It seems to not show the alternate menu (or any menu for that manner) in between 992px - 762px (this is where the alternate menu shows up)   I'd like the alternate menu (drop down) in between that space as well - any idea where to start? I've tried everything I can think of that appeared obvious to me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your menu width is too long for the screen width 992 ~ 762px.

It drops under logo and behind banner, the banner's z-index is causing it not visible.

Try to trigger your menu to change to alternate dropdown menu within 1024px screen width (eg. max-width:1023px) and it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!   What attribute would that be exactly.  As I said, I'm new to responsive, and the #navigation element has SO many defining attributes. - I don't know where to look.  Graphic design is my forte, I'm just trying to help out a friend and my knowledge is a little limited.

Comment: I guess what I want to ask is, where exactly do I put the max-width:1023px;   ?

Comment: Try to add another media query @media (max-width:1023px), then move the css in gozha-nav.css line line174 ~ line 236  into the 1023px query. The rest of the details need your own tweaking already.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still having an issue.  It's still not working on a couple resolutions.  is there a minor tweak involved?  This is my point of reference  http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=http%3A//rdesignmedia.com/itechrepairs&w=768&h=1024&a=22

If you notice, it won't work on the Ipad ALL or the one below it

Comment: my mistake, forgot to refresh, did you try on actual iPad for the page? as I'm looking at it on my iPad.

Comment: I haven't tried it on an actual Ipad yet.  I tried it on a Ipad (large) and it came out fine the last time, but I was told an air/mini doesn't work.   What ipad do you have? EDIT: I haven't had someone try it on an Air/Mini yet.

Comment: iPad mini. for alternative method, if you are using chrome. you should be knowing that the development tools are able to change your browser to view as various devices. Click F12 on your chrome and look for the mobile icon on the left side of the developer tools menu.

Comment: Hmm.. That's awesome Thanks for the tip. I knew about the developer tools but not the resolution change.  Now that I know it works on a mini, I'll test it on an air tomorrow.   Thanks for the tips!  Cheers.